How to set flink taskmanager name to be the same as the docker host name?
Is there anyway to have the flink taskamanger name shown at the top of the Flink UI (image below):

Match the docker hostname

If thats not possible then what would be the best way to map the two? For example given a taskamanger how do I map this to the docker container?
I understand one way is to check the container ip addresses but hoping there would be a more straightforward way?
Thanks in advance
